# Custom animation for Toast enter/exit?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to have my Toast's entrance and exit animations customized. Specifically, I want to make it appear instantly (no fade-in) and disappear like normal (fade-out).

Is there a way I can use animations with a toast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toasts are displayed using a system template that can't be changed so short answer is no you cant change the toast animation.

however you can make your own view that resembles a toast and animate it however you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with the stock Android Toast class. The Toast class is limited to four system animations and will not accept animations from your project.

See: [Android add custom animation to Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034362/android-add-custom-animation-to-toast/20527461#20527461)